# Read-only Hibernate entity in multiple sessions

Tags: hibernate, caching

I have **read-only** (marked @Immutable) Hibernate entities that I wish to have in multiple open sessions. There are multiple sessions because processing, including database writes of other entities that have FK to the read-only entity, is being done on parallel threads.

My naïve approach was to use `session.update(read_only_thing)` to bring them into the session, but the upshot there is `illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions` error when I save. What is the correct idiom?

I would rather not rewrite the project to use Spring.

Answer (score 0):

And, I finally figured it out. I made sure to use `EAGER` fetch type, so they weren't proxy objects any more.